# Notification cant able to pass data via intent in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("thoughtObject", message);
    intent.putExtra("isFromNotification", true);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    int requestCode = 0;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).
            setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.noti_logo)).setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setContentTitle(title + "").setContentText(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build());
```

have use this code but in MainActivity cant able to get it from Extras.. please help me !

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String messageThoughtObject = "";

        if (extras != null) {
            Log.e("extras -->" + isFromNotification, extras.toString() + " --->");
            messageThoughtObject = extras.getString("thoughtObject");
            isFromNotification = extras.getBoolean("isFromNotification");
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        thoughtObject = gson.fromJson(messageThoughtObject, ThoughtsModelClass.class);
//        if (isFromNotification) {
//            showThoughtFragment(thoughtObject);
//        }

        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: post your main activity code as well

Comment: Since, `putExtra()` is pretty overloaded, you need make sure you use the right data type while trying to get those values in `MainActivity`.